# Sqlite 3 Insert and Replace fails on more than 1 unique column

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite

I am using a table to store votes  of different users on different polls.

Table has following structure.

```
id   |  poll_id  |   opt   |  ip_address

id : auto increment

poll_id : (STRING UNIQUE) unique for a particular poll  

opt : (STRING) option selected by user    

ip_address: (STRING UNIQUE) ip address of user
```

This is my query

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO tbl_poll(id,poll_id,opt,ip_addr) VALUES (null,'$poll_id','$opt','$ip_addr')
```

*`(Here $poll_id, $opt and $ip_addr are php variables which holds the respective values)`*

Now, the scenario is like this,

User 'A' votes for option 2 of poll_id 'mypoll'. Query works perfectly. (Does insert)

User 'A' changes mind and votes for option 5 of poll_id 'mypoll'. Query works perfectly. (Does replace)

But if User 'A' votes for option 4 of poll_id 'yourpoll'.  **Query fails (It does a replace)** but it should insert a new record with poll_id 'yourpoll'

I think, it considers the `unqiue` constraint of `ip_address` only but not the `poll_id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description on the desired functionality, it would seem that you want `poll_id` and `ip_address` to be a *unique pair* or *compound unique*.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_poll ( 
    id         INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    poll_id    STRING NOT NULL,
    ip_address STRING NOT NULL,
    opt        STRING NULL,
    CONSTRAINT 'unique_vote_per_poll_per_ip_address' UNIQUE ( poll_id, ip_address )  ON CONFLICT REPLACE 
);
```

Comment: Let me try and get back to you :)

Comment: Works perfect. Can you explain which line made it *compound unique* ? and why there's `TEXT` before `STRING`. I know its a very basic question but I have never worked on sqlite before.

Also, is my query fine ?

Comment: @Jashwant: Those `TEXT` were just an artifact in my answer, removed them now. The last line makes the `CONSTRAINT` on `UNIQUE( poll_id, ip_address )`.

Comment: I get that but why is it different from my version. I made both `poll_id` and `ip_address` unique too.

Comment: @Jashwant: You made `poll_id` and `ip_address` `UNIQUE` on their own. My constraint makes them `UNIQUE` as a _pair_.

Comment: Also, I noticed that I no longer need `INSERT OR REPLACE`. This 
`INSERT INTO tbl_poll(id,poll_id,opt,ip_address) VALUES (null,'jsfgw','44','117.199.45.121')` works fine due to `ON CONFLICT REPLACE`

Comment: @Jashwant: Oh yes, indeed. Doesn't it feel better? :P

Comment: A lot . Sqlite 3 is great. So lite and so powerful. I am enjoying it

Answer (score 1):

No, this is correct behaviour.
You have a `UNIQUE` constraint on `ip_address`, therefore you may not have two records with the same `ip_address`.
Put your `UNIQUE`constraint on the pair `(poll_id, ip_address)` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now that compound `unique` is different from separate `unique`.