# Sqlite 3: select and count together with group by and without group by

Tags: sql, sqlite

Ahead of this question
[Sqlite 3 Insert and Replace fails on more than 1 unique column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972256/sqlite-3-insert-and-replace-fails-on-more-than-1-unique-column/10972316#comment14328588_10972316)

I have a table with schema,

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_poll ( 
    id         INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    poll_id    STRING NOT NULL,
    ip_address STRING NOT NULL,
    opt        STRING NULL,
    CONSTRAINT 'unique_vote_per_poll_per_ip_address' UNIQUE ( poll_id, ip_address )  ON CONFLICT REPLACE 
);
```

When I do,

```
select opt,count(opt) as count from tbl_poll where poll_id = 'jsfw' group by opt
```

Result is

```
opt            count
0                4
2                2 
3                2
```

*i.e. 4 users have selected 0 option, 2 and 3 option is selected by 2 and 2 users respectively.*

Is there any way so I can get a result like following

```
   opt            count    percent
    0                4        0.5       
    2                2        0.25 
    3                2        0.25
```

where percent = count / total count

If I can get total count i.e. (4+2+2 = 8 ) that will solve my problem too.

I have tried this,

```
   select opt,count(opt) as count from tbl_poll where poll_id = 'jsfw'
```

but it doesn't work as no of columns are not same.

Comment: Are you using all of this servers? Some functions and statementes are different across them.

Comment: I am using sqlite3 , tagged all because I thought its more of a sql question than specific server. Btw edited my tags and title to reflect sqlite3 solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT opt
     , COUNT(*) AS count
     , ROUND(CAST(COUNT(*) AS REAL)/total, 2) AS percent 
FROM tbl_poll 
  CROSS JOIN
    ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS total 
      FROM tbl_poll 
      WHERE poll_id = 'jsfw' 
    ) AS t
WHERE poll_id = 'jsfw' 
GROUP BY opt ;
```

Comment: 0 always. I guess because of the problem of value of  `1/5`

Comment: @Jashwant: Yes it is, ypercube is missing a `cast(... as real)` in the division.

Comment: Changed `COUNT(*)/total AS percent` to `cast(COUNT (opt) as real)/total AS percent`, it works great. @ypercube  , please edit it , so I can mark as answer.

Comment: One more question, how can I `cast` to 2 decimal places only ?

Comment: `round(cast(COUNT (opt) as real)/total,2) AS percent` casts to 2 decimal places

Answer (score 0):

If you know all of the possible values from opt, you can use `CASE WHEN` statement:

```
SELECT COUNT(opt) as total, SUM(CASE WHEN opt = '0' OR opt IS NULL OR TRIM(opt) = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as total0, SUM(CASE WHEN opt = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as total1, ... FROM tbl_poll WHERE poll_id = 'jsfw'
```

This will give you:

```
total    total0    total1    ...
8        4         0         ...
```

Let me know if this isn't a closed set of options.

The sintax follows:

```
CASE WHEN condition THEN result_for_true ELSE result_for_false END
CASE WHEN condition1 THEN result_for_1 WHEN condition2 THEN result_for_2 ELSE result_for_false_on_all END
```

Comment: Its not a closed set of options. (Its now fixed for 4 options but not necessary)

Comment: But its not fixed. Current poll has 4 options, but next poll may have more or less than 4 options.